# db2cli license file not being used

Tags: db2, centos, db2-midrange

I'm using the db2 driver for CLI and ODBC to configure an ODBC connection to DB2 on IBM i/OS from CentOS. I'm trying the following command:

```
db2cli execsql -connstring "protocol=TCPIP;database=MyDB;hostname=MyHost;ServiceName=446;uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPass"
```

And getting the following error which seems pretty straightforward:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968
```

I believe I have the paths and everything correct:

```
# Environment
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/DB2/odbc_cli/clidriver/bin/
export DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/DB2/odbc_cli/clidriver
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/DB2/odbc_cli/clidriver/lib

license file: /opt/DB2/odbc_cli/clidriver/license/db2consv_is.lic
```

I have also attempted to move the license to a few other paths without any success. It is valid and works on another (windows) installation without issues. Any idea what I can troubleshoot from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a version mismatch between the license file and the ODBC driver. The licence .lic file has `ProductVersion=10.5` in text in the body. Using the matching driver version has fixed the issue for me.